# Web API attribute routing HTTP 404

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api2

I can't make attribute routing to work in Web API 2. I did not start with Web API template project, I think it was Empty project. Convention based routing works, but when I add Route attribute to controller actions, I get 404 error. I find a lot of posts regarding this, but none of them helped me. It could be related to the project template, something I have to do manually since I started with Empty project. I do call MapHttpAttributeRoutes method in WebApiConfig and the class iheriting ApiController is public. What else do I have to do in WebApiConfig class and Application_Start method?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my WebApiConfig file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{oId}/{oTypeCode}/{oTypeName}/{email}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Xrm", email = RouteParameter.Optional, oId = RouteParameter.Optional, oTypeCode = RouteParameter.Optional, oTypeName = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
```

And Application_Start method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
```

Comment: Share some of your code. Looking at that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, my fault. I was trying to pass an email address as a path parameter. Sending it as query string parameter works. I am not sure how would it look like to send as part of the path, but it works for me this way.